# Is the Union File System (UFS) concept only exist in Docker?

Tags: docker

I'm a beginner of Docker. When I read about docker's union file system, I was wondering about "Is the UFS concept only exist in Docker?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Union mounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) of various kinds have been around for a long time, they are really not a novel idea.

[UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) is but one implementation of this idea and has been developed independently of Docker.

Docker actually uses various implementations of this idea, depending on what's available and configured: [AUFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/), [OverlayFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/)